# HTML / PHP string is not passing IP to WHOIS

Tags: php, html, whois

I am not sure if WHOIS changed their format, since it used to work, but now it does not. Does anyone know how to change this line of code so that the IP address is passed to WHOIS? Currently the WHOIS text box is empty. Thank you.

```
<a href="http://tools.whois.net/whoisbyip/<?php echo $row['ip'];?>" target = "_blank">ISP Details</a></td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL certainly doesn't work now.  I tried `http://tools.whois.net/whoisbyip`, and I'm redirected to `https://tools.whois.net/default.aspx`, where I can only search for a domain name, not an IP address.  So whatever service they had that allowed you to do this no longer works.

I searched for the URL you posted and found `http://whois.domaintools.com/`, which appears to be the new URL and lets you search by IP, and from there you can get the appropriate URL to do what you want.  So your code would then look like this:

```
<a href="http://whois.domaintools.com/<?php echo $row['ip'];?>" target = "_blank">ISP Details</a></td>
```

However, in addition to changing the URL, they've also added a CAPTCHA, so the method you're using will no longer work.

**UPDATED**

The one you posted in your comment would work like this:

```
https://www.ultratools.com/tools/ipWhoisLookupResult?ipAddress=X.X.X.X
```

So integrated into your code, it would look like this:

```
<a href="https://www.ultratools.com/tools/ipWhoisLookupResult?ipAddress=<?php echo $row['ip'];?>" target = "_blank">ISP Details</a></td>
```

Comment: Ok, thank you. Is there another provider that would work? If so, how would the code be configured. Thank you again.

Comment: Could be.. but I don't know of any.  If you find one and need help writing the code, you can post back here with that.

Comment: Would this one work? Thanks. https://www.ultratools.com/tools/ipWhoisLookup

Comment: Yes, I updated my answer to show you how that one would work with your code.